# MDT Fails at post apply cleanup step

Tags: windows-10, mdt

I have a task sequence to install a custom image, standard client task sequence stuff. Tested and works just fine in a VM.

However, running it on a laptop here, it installs, boots into task sequence, and starts running.  But it fails at Post-Apply Cleanup step, after which a blank white Wizard.hta window comes up and does nothing.  Once I close this window, the computer automatically reboots then ends the task sequence.

Snippit of my smsts.log:

```
Start executing the command line: cscript.exe "%SCRIPTROOT%\LTIApply.wsf" /post 
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
Expand a string:    TSManager   12/15/2021 11:15:57 PM  936 (0x03A8)
Executing command line: cscript.exe "%SCRIPTROOT%\LTIApply.wsf" /post
Process completed with exit code 1
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
Failed to run the action: Post-Apply Cleanup. 
Incorrect function. (Error: 00000001; Source: Windows)  
Executing in non SMS standalone mode. Ignoring send a task execution status message request
Set a global environment variable _SMSTSLastActionRetCode=1
Set a global environment variable _SMSTSLastActionName=Post-Apply Cleanup   
Set a global environment variable _SMSTSLastActionSucceeded=false
Clear local default environment
Let the parent group (State Restore) decides whether to continue execution  
The execution of the group (State Restore) has failed and the execution has been aborted. An action failed.
Operation aborted (Error: 80004004; Source: Windows)
Failed to run the last action: Post-Apply Cleanup. Execution of task sequence failed.
Incorrect function. (Error: 00000001; Source: Windows)  
Executing in non SMS standalone mode. Ignoring send a task execution status message request
Task Sequence Engine failed! Code: enExecutionFail  
****************************************************************************    
Task sequence execution failed with error code 80004005
Cleaning Up.
```

So it tries to run apply, fails, then does nothing.  It also doesn't help that it's failing to upload the logs to the share, stating "An invalid SLShare value of `\\10.10.1.197\mdt\logs\`" even though I can verify that that is correct, and the laptop has a network connection once it reboots (can't see during TS)

Why is it failing at `Post-Apply cleanup`?

---

Edit: my BDD.log snippit

```
ZTIGather processing completed successfully.
Event 41001 sent: ZTIGather processing completed successfully.  
Command completed, return code = -2147467259
Litetouch deployment failed, Return Code = -2147467259  0x80004005  
Event 41014 sent: Litetouch deployment failed, Return Code = -2147467259  0x80004005
For more information, consult the task sequencer log ...\SMSTS.LOG.
Property RetVal is now = -2147467259
Validating connection to \\10.10.1.97\mdt\logs\
Mapping server share: \\10.10.1.97\mdt
Already connected to server 10.10.1.97
An invalid SLShare value of \\10.10.1.97\mdt\logs\ was specified.
CleanStartItems Complete
Unregistering TSCore.dll.
About to run command: wscript.exe "C:\MININT\Scripts\LTICleanup.wsf"
```

Comment: SLshare should have \\ in front. Also make sure that account under which MDT is running has permissions to write to this share.
BDD.log may give more detailed error description

Comment: @Hardoman it has permission and is typed correctly (formatting error here).  The permissions for the SLShare are the same as the deployment share.  BDDLog just gave me the generic error code (something like -2147467259) and told me to check other logs.  It gave no information as to what was happening.  Either way I'll add a snippit to my question.

Comment: I'm sure the issue is with SLShare value. If you remove it from the config it would complete successfully. Also try to remove trailing \ after "\logs".